# Data Handling and Manipulation

Tags: excel

So I've tried every trick I know and I've searched through Google and I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible.I have a column which has let's say 10000 rows of data, many of which are duplicates. Is there a way to select a certain datum, find all of its duplicates in the column and then fill out in a blank cell beside them a specific note( like for example, 'recorded' or 'yes') all at the same time?

edit: sorry for the confusion for others

example:

> A(column) B(column)
>
> 1124
>
> 53215
>
> 34567
>
> 12312
>
> 1124
>
> 4667
>
> 53215
>
> 1124
>
> 1124
>
> 53215
>
> 463437
>
> 53215
>
> 123421321
>
> 2335
>
> 478
>
> 7976976
>
> 1124
>
> 53215
>
> 86547464
>
> 53215
>
> 1124

How do you only select 1124? and then add yes(only an example) beside 1124 in column B.

EDIT 2: I added 53215 as another example since the formula given to me below already kind of works. I should also say that I have different sets of duplicates requiring certain notes.

Comment: Yes, it is.  But to help us help you, I recommend you read the HELP pages for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question for clarity.

Comment: As you refer to a certain datum then look at filtering your range and then inputing your datum of interest into the search box. You can then  fill the top cell of adjacent cell with a comment and autofill down.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld edited for clarity.

Comment: @QHarr autofill down? Even though they may not necessarily be in consecutive order?

Comment: You would have applied the filter for your item of interest. Datum is singular so I was thinking of it as your filter term to go in the filter box. All visible would thus be the same.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I think I know what you're trying to do now. Since I'm somewhat dug in here, let me give it a whirl. I'm providing this as a different answer as the question has evolved.

First, I think you only want to note a duplicate one time, i.e. not note a duplicate over and over. To do this, again assuming data is in column A:

```
// copy this down
Cell B1: =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,"duplicate","")
```

Then, assuming you want to assign these to email 1, email 2, etc., let's set a reference number and a reference table with emails:

```
Cell C1: 0

// copy these down
Cell C2: =IF(B2="duplicate",C1+1,C1)
Cell D2: =IF(B2="duplicate",VLOOKUP(C2,E:F,2,FALSE),"")
```

The above gets emails from column F based on the reference in column E. populate the reference table with sequently numbers going down in column E and emails to the right of this in column F.

I think something like this is what you are getting at?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in column A and begins in row 1:

```
// In B1 - copy this down
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,"duplicate","")
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this already kind of works for me, but I have different sets of duplicates requiring specific notes, sorry if this sounds obvious, the lack of sleep is getting to me, but do I just change "duplicate" to a different one and it should just automatically apply to all its duplicates? And that should apply to all the different sets of duplicates? EDIT: I tired what I said, and editing the formula inside does not automatically work and it affects other previous notes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you are asking if you could use this formula to note something other than "duplicate," yes, just change the word. This formula is counting the number of instances to the left and all above. If it is more than one, it prints "duplicate." Change the word to anything you want and it will display that if duplicate. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You understood my question correctly.I added an edit to my reply but you may not see it. Tried doing that but I guess it affects other previous notes if I do that? I already edited my main post with an example. I have 1124 and 53215 as an example and 1124 and 53215 have different notes to them, and take note, some of the datum have 100s of duplicates to them, all of them are ordered overlapping each other like the example above

Comment: If a note is specific to an entry, for example 1124 says something and 53215 has something else, and these notes are specific to the number, you may want another table to get the note from with vlookup. If you want to manually put notes for any where there is a dupe, I'd suggest a column B to highlight the dupe, then another column C for the note. If you explain the application I might be better able to help. ?

Comment: Hi, you've been really helpful so far, thanks. Hmm, basically I'm listing down emails, can't really reveal anything more than that. I'm hoping it's possible to put email A to 1124 all at the same time, then move on to 53215 and list down email B all at the same time.

Comment: Did the new answer I posted answer your question, or at least help you get to a final solution? Note that if this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.